# Error while running simple R shiny app on R Studio server 1.0.153

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am using R studio server 1.0.153 on citrix virtual machine. I just wrote a simple R shiny program and saved the file as app.R.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody()
)
server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When clicked on run app, I get the following error snapshot. Please help me to run the app.

[image: Error page]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body, skin="blue")
server <- function(input, output) { }


app <- shinyApp(ui,server)
runApp(app,host="0.0.0.0",port=5050)
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but still the same issue. Please help.

Comment: I guess the problem with citrix and R. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202422056-Running-RStudio-on-Terminal-Server-Citrix-Environment